# share variable between components using event emitter in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I have 2 components, Profile & Images (both having different routes). I want to access one variable from Profile in the Image component.

I have one button in **BusinessList** component, when the user clicks that button it should redirect to home page, where I add one item to localstorage.

In home page profile, images, and contacts are in different tabs.

After button is clicked in BusinessList, the  profile tab is activated. Here I am getting the local storage item, storing it one variable - the same variable I want to access it from Image, contacts --- tabs

Here is my **Profile Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: 'module.id',
  selector: 'my-profile',
  templateUrl: '../views/business.images.html',
})


export class BusinessProfileComponent {
  public userAction: any;


  constructor(private router: Router, activeroute: ActivatedRoute,
              BusinessSettingService: BusinessSettingService) {


    this.userAction = localStorage.getItem("action")
    BusinessSettingService.userTakenAction.next(this.userAction);

    console.log(this.userAction, '  this.userAction')
  }
```

}

Here **userAction** is shareable data between components,

**Image Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: 'module.id',
  selector: 'my-core',
  templateUrl: '../views/business.images.html',
})

export class BusinessImagesComponent{

 constructor( private router: Router, BusinessSettingService: BusinessSettingService) {

    BusinessSettingService.userTakenAction.subscribe(value => {this.userImageaction= !value;})
}
```

**BusinessSettingService**

```
import { Injectable,Output,EventEmitter  }     from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BusinessSettingService {

  public userTakenAction: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

I created a custom service for components using `EventEmitter`, is it a good approach to solve this scenario, or is there a better way to do this?

I am unable get the userAction value in Image component.. Please help me to solve this

Comment: Are the Profile and Image components appearing on different pages (via different routes)? Or do they appear as components on the same page?

Comment: Yes, different pages(via different routes)

Comment: Ok, so you want one component to notify the other when something happens? And send it some data?

Comment: yes , I want take data form profile in image component

Comment: If both components are on the same parent page then you could use a [shared service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#bidirectional-service) or other methods listed in the doco to communicate between 2 components.

Comment: I did n't understood what you say

Comment: I edited my post, what exactly I want, Can you please check it once

Comment: Ok I don't understand how the tabs are related to the routes? Is the tab content created via `router-outlet`? Perhaps you can post some `html` to make the question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your BusinessSettingService to following one:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class BusinessSettingService { 

// Observable  for selection source
  private userActionSource = new Subject<any>();

// Observable for selection stream
  userActionStream$ = this.userActionSource.asObservable();

userActionUpdated(userAction: any) {
    console.log('user action is: ' + userAction);
    this.userActionSource.next(userAction);
  }

}
```

Now, in both Profile and Image component, initiate your BusinessSettingService in constructor and simply subscribe to this observer and update the value.

In component constructor:

```
constructor (private businessSettingService: BusinessSettingService) {}
```

and then subscribe it and update the value:

```
this.businessSettingService.userActionUpdated(this.userAction);
```

Similarly, In your Image component, subscribe to this observable and get the updated value using following code.

```
  this.businessSettingService.userActionStream$.subscribe(
   value => {
       this.userAction = value;
   }
);
```

Hope this helps.